# Rails SMTPAuthenticationError - Username and Password not accepted

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am using Rails 6 and trying to get the action mailer to work on development. It all works fine, until it comes to the SMTP Authentication. This is my config:

```
config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
  :address => "smtp.gmail.com",
  :port => 587,
  :user_name => "name@gmail.com",
  :password => "gmail-password",
  :authentication => :plain,
  :enable_starttls_auto => true,
}
config.action_mailer.perform_caching = true
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => "localhost:3000" }
```

I did allow google to allow less secure apps. What is the problem with it. This is the log:

```
[ActiveJob] [ActionMailer::MailDeliveryJob] [3d533896-b670-404f-baa7-aaf9ecd8ff81] Error performing 
ActionMailer::MailDeliveryJob (Job ID: 3d533896-b670-404f-baa7-aaf9ecd8ff81) from Async(mailers) in 
9827.83ms: Net::SMTPAuthenticationError (535-5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted. Learn more at
):

C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/2.6.0/net/smtp.rb:981:in `check_auth_response'
C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/2.6.0/net/smtp.rb:736:in `auth_plain'
C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/2.6.0/net/smtp.rb:728:in `authenticate'
C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/2.6.0/net/smtp.rb:565:in `do_start'
C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/2.6.0/net/smtp.rb:518:in `start'
```

What more does it need to work?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error. The issue was the `Gmail password` was incorrect since the Google APP was no longer available. So I had to recreate the app on my Gmail account and regenerate the password and that was it!